# Linux : Which process is appending to file?

Tags: linux, process, daemon

How to kill the process which is keep appending to file `a.txt`. Process is created by the following command

```
daemon `while [ 1 -eq 1 ]; do echo $RANDOM >> a.txt; sleep 2; done` &
```

Now its keep appending in `a.txt`. I tried rebooting also but the process is still running..

Comment: A process certainly does not survive a reboot :-) If it exists after the reboot, then it was restarted.

Comment: You want to take a look at the `fuser` utility. Read the "man page": `man fuser`. Also a simple "grep" over the output of `ps aux` helps to find out the process id which is what you need to send a "kill" signal to the process.

Comment: check if there is a cron in place

Comment: @arkascha I tried fuser but it is not showing anything.. I think each time it is acquiring file and closing connection after that..

Comment: Ah, indeed, you are right. So what about that other approach I wrote? Something like `ps aux|grep ">> a\.txt"` should show the process ID which you can then use in a kill command: `kill <process ID>` to terminate the process. You may even try `kill -9 <process ID>`. But as mentioned before: something must ahve restarted that process after the reboot. Without removing that detail (whatever you did) you won't get happy...

Comment: That is also not working ... I have tried that also.... :(

Answer (score 0):

What OS is installed?

check the "crontab -e". if there is something likes this, remove it
 - @reboot /path/to/script

Or make a grep in '/etc/init.d/'